# "C" file appending problems

Tags: c, file, append, printf, fopen

I have a project in C, in which file appending for some reason doesn't work. The snippet of code in question is this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("tanulok.txt", "a");

if (fp == NULL){
    printf("Nem tudtuk megnyitni a fajlt!");
    return;
} else{

fprintf(fp, "\n%s %s %s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", uj.veznev, uj.kernev, uj.neptun, uj.eloadaskod, uj.gyakkod, uj.kzh1, uj.kzh2, uj.kzh3, uj.kzh4, uj.kzh5, uj.kzh6, uj.nzh1, uj.nzh2, uj.nhfpont, uj.szorgpont, uj.gyakh, uj.labh);
fclose(fp);
```

`uj` is a structure containing strings and integers. The file is a text file containing 500 or so lines of text, and I'd like to append this to the end of it. Thank you all for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Is the content of file getting overwritten?

Comment: Can you perhaps replicate the issue on repl.it (https://repl.it/languages/c)? It can make it easier to understand and debug the issue.

Comment: Nothing happens to the file, it doesnt get appended to the end. @Fredrik I thought if i use "a" in fopen, the stream is already positioned at the and of the file, right?

Comment: @MosheJonathanGordonRadian The problem is that the proj is quite big and across multiple files, so im not sure if that is going to work like that, will it?

Comment: There is no apparent reason from the code posted. Can you please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem? Is it any different if you add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` statement?

Comment: Are you sure the process is run with the right permissions to touch the files?

Comment: @Fredrik If i didn't have the permission, wouldn't the pionter be NULL, therefore it would've been detected?

Comment: @WeatherVane will try, thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane wow. This fixed the issue, I have no idea why! Thanks a lot tho! Could you please explain what "fflush(stdout)" does exactly?

Comment: Because the output is buffered, and `fflush` empties the buffer to the device. Sometimes a final newline will do that (not guaranteed) but I noticed there isn't one. I only omit the newline if I am about to output more in another statement which completes the line.

Comment: But `fclose()` calls `fflush()` as part of its cleanup... or at least, it's supposed to. Weird.

Comment: @Shawn that's a different file, and isn't executed here anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane Huh? There's only one file being opened, written to and closed in that code.

Comment: @Shawn my comment said "add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` statement" not after the `fprintf`. There are *two* files here.

Comment: @WeatherVane Then that *really* makes no sense how it could have fixed the text not showing up.

Comment: Heaven's sake, because it was still in the buffer, and the `stdout` was not yet flushed or closed. The file could not be opened for appending, and the error message was not seen.

Comment: @WeatherVane But OP isn't writing data to stdout (Aside from a message if the file isn't being opened, but that case wouldn't fix the issue like OP said it did)

Comment: @KonstantinLaveczky The idea would be to copy just the file handling logic into the main function and see if you can get it to fail in the same way.

Comment: Guys, couldn't the problem be me not using "malloc" at these data sizes and the stack flowing over as well? Regardless, it fixed my problem, although I don't understand the solution fully, credit is given where it's due, so: [link](https://imgur.com/a/jyguyQi) @WeatherVane :D

Comment: If your intended file append now works, then you have a bug somewhere else, which has been masked by adding the statement.

Comment: It does work, I'm still trying to figure out what it could be, couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: Make sure you end printed messages (and lines in files) with a newline — put the newline at the end of the format string, not the start.  Also, report errors on standard error, and end those with newlines too.